# Flask не сохраняет session

Tags: python, flask, сессия

Столкнулся с проблемой, что Flask не сохраняет сессии. Я создал простое приложение:

```
from flask import request, Flask, session
import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'lkasjd;flkasdjf'
app.premanent_session_lifetime = True
app.config['PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME'] = datetime.timedelta(days=3)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    if not session.get('count'):
        session['count'] = 0
    session['count'] += 1
    return f'Count {session["count"]}'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Вроде как сессии должны жить 3 дня, но после закрытия баузера они стираются. Я уже пробовал и в вирутальном окружении и без него, все равно сессии не сохраняются.

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему вот так:

```
@app.before_request
def change_session_lifetime():
    session.permanent = True
    session.permanent_session_lifetime = datetime.timedelta(days=3)
```